# Как защитить файл admin.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache

есть в папке public_html файл с именем admin.php нужно защитить его логин:пароль

писал так .HTACCESS :

```
<FilesMatch "admin.php">
AuthName "Member Only"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /home/logincpanel/.htpasswd
require valid-user
</FilesMatch>
```

для .htpasswd `user:passs`

Загрузил на сервер два этих файла в public_html и

получил Internal Server Error

Прочитал коментарий: "После переноса файлов в целевую директорию надо отредактировать путь к файлу .htpasswd в .htaccess . Если из примера, то надо добавить secret-files в путь. Чтобы было: //secret-files /.htpasswd Иначе словите Internal Server Error"

не совсем понял что надо сделать?

Answer (score 1):

**.htaccess:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^Basic.*
    RewriteRule (.*) admin.php?http=%{HTTP:Authorization} [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

**admin.php:**

```
<?php
$login = 'admin';
$password = 'admin';

function auth($login, $password) {
   $user = [];
   if (preg_match('/^Basic\s+(.*)$/i', filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'http'), $user)) {
        list($user, $pass) = explode(':', base64_decode($user[1]));
        if ($user === $login && $pass === $password) {
            return [$login, $password];
        }
   }
   return [];
}


if ($auth = auth($login, $password)) {
    var_dump($auth);
} else {
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Restricted Area"');
    header('HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized');
    exit("Access denied.");
}
```